# CSS animations not working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-animations

I am in the middle of building a website for a client, for which I work from two computers.
On the homepage of this website (http://www.the-language-people.co.uk/) some of the images load with a little CSS transition. 
These transitions work perfectly fine from one of my computers, but don't work at all from the other one.

They work fine on Chrome on my Windows 7 desktop. They don't work on my Windows 8.1 laptop, also from Chrome.

Why do these animations work on Chrome on one computer but not on the other??

NOTE: I did not create these animations myself, I am using the Visual Composer on a WordPress theme, so I did not make any mistakes myself in creating these animations, as I did not write the code for them myself.

Comment: I don't know where to find the code; I just enabled the CSS animation via a visual composer. In any case my question isn't about the code because it works perfectly fine on another computer in Chrome, I think it might be an issue either with Windows 8.1 or with the Chrome settings on my second computer. Once somebody manages to discover what the error is then maybe they could paste the code themselves, as I don't know where to find it.

Comment: Point - didn't realise. Comment removed. Are you in Desktop mode with Chrome Win 8.1 or Windows 8 mode?

Comment: I am in Desktop mode on my Windows 8.1 computer

Comment: As am I, and they're working fine for me. Windows 8.1 and Chrome 38.0.2125.101 in Desktop mode.

Comment: Hmm, see that's the problem. I can't pinpoint why it's not working, but it just doesn't.

Comment: Can you describe your setup? Computer, OS version, Chrome version, internet adapter and router types, etc.